# beginner android development question

Tags: android, xml, background

I was following a tutorial on youtube, and I was trying to put a background image and I keep having an error in eclipse. I placed the image in the drawable-hdpi folder. Then in the xml, I have:

```
LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/background_test.png"
```

But, it keeps saying that it can't find the image. I don't know what I'm doing wrong. Please help. Thank you.

Comment: Check whether R.java file created or not?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just remove `.png'

```
android:background="@drawable/background_test"
```

Comment: wow, well that worked. Thank you. but what if I had two things with the same name but different file formats, how would I differentiate them?

Comment: @de1337ed it would be best to rename them to something different. Its just good practice and helps you keep everything straight. Maybe pic1jpg.jpg and pic1png.png.

Comment: ya, I guess I'll just do that. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

You can just reference it like you did but without .png. also are you closing your linear layout?

Comment: yes, I closed it, and it worked when I took away the ending, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

you have to use only lowercase letters without any special charaters when u name the image.